# Get program name from executable path (or from hWnd, or from pid) in C++

Tags: c++, winapi, process

- I've got the **HWND** of a window,
- with `GetWindowThreadProcessId` i get
  the **pid** of it's process,
- and with `GetModuleFileNameEx` i get the
  **executable path** (I use `PathFindFileName` to get the
  **executable name**).

However, I can't seem to find any way (if there is any) to get the program's name. For example, for the executable chrome.exe, I'd like to get the name "Google Chrome".

Could you please help me out?

Edit:

Thank you all! Using the references you recommended, I came up with this:

```
CString csProductName;
DWORD cbFileVersionInfo = GetFileVersionInfoSize(pszProcessPath, NULL);
if (cbFileVersionInfo)
{
    BYTE *fileVersionInfo = new BYTE[cbFileVersionInfo];
    TCHAR *pszFileDesc = NULL;
    DWORD cchFileDesc;

    if (GetFileVersionInfo(pszProcessPath, 0, cbFileVersionInfo, fileVersionInfo))
    {
        CString csFileDescSubBlock;
        csFileDescSubBlock.Format(L"\\StringFileInfo\\040904E4\\ProductName");

        DWORD cbLanguageInfoSize = VerQueryValue(fileVersionInfo,
            csFileDescSubBlock.GetString(), 
            (LPVOID*)&pszFileDesc, 
            (PUINT)&cchFileDesc);
    }

    csProductName = pszFileDesc;
    delete[] fileVersionInfo;
}
```

... which works as expected... but only for the application calling it. If the executable name is an other one, it returns null, and cchFileDesc is set to 0.

I've read that "If the specified version-information structure exists, **and version information is available**, the return value is nonzero." Is it possible that I don't have enough rights to read that information? Because it sure exists - task manager prints it for the process's details. Does calling these functions depend on anything else than the process's path?

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2789017/how-to-get-information-about-a-windows-executable-exe-using-c

Comment: @Gabriel: your comment is the answer... Linking to Jerry Coffin's excellent answer there. Why not write it as an answer? Or, is this a case where we should vote to close since it's so similar/identical?

Comment: Thank you, I've seen that post, but GetFileVersionInfo, and VerQueryValue seem to return a structure of type VS_FIXEDFILEINFO, which doesn't provide the information I need (the "file description", I believe).

Comment: @loanna - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms647464(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here, as an answer :)

[How to get information about a Windows executable (.exe) using C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2789017/how-to-get-information-about-a-windows-executable-exe-using-c)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [GetWindowText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633520%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: GetWindowText returns a "full" name of the window, something like "c++ get program name from executable name - Google Search", for a Chrome window whith a Google search on it.