# How to retrieve application name from pid or exe path

Tags: windows

How can I retrieve **Application Name** from the given PID or exe path.

e.g. My input is:

```
C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe
```

and PID is:

```
342.
```

From this input I want to retrieve its Product Name i.e Internet Explorer.

Any help?

Comment: Do you want to retrieve it through code? If so, which language, C++ or C#?

Comment: You may find some help [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2789017/how-to-get-information-about-a-windows-executable-exe-using-c). This looks like what you want.

Comment: I found Windows API to achieve this. VerQueryValue do exactly what I want.