# How to determine unique application from a HWND or PID?

Tags: hook, pid, msdn, user32, kernel32

I want to monitor OS-level program foreground changes, but I'm having trouble uniquifying the returned application.

I'm using a combination of `SetWinEventHook`, `EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND` and `WinEventProc` callback to get the foreground change events. I'm able to inspect both the top-level `hwnd`, the window title, the path, and the associated `PID`. This works well.

```
hwnd = GetAncestor(hwnd, GA_ROOTOWNER);
GetWindowText(hwnd, text, 1024);
GetWindowModuleFileName(hwnd, moduleFileName, 1024);
pid = GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, pointer);
```

example output:

```
pid=2676, text=Calculator, moduleFileName=Calculator
pid=3460, text=Calculator, moduleFileName=Calculator
pid=2676, text=Calculator, moduleFileName=Calculator
pid=1128, text=EditPad Pro 7 - [*Untitled 1], moduleFileName=D:\Program Files\java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe
pid=3460, text=Calculator, moduleFileName=Calculator
pid=1128, text=EditPad Pro 7 - [*Untitled 2], moduleFileName=D:\Program Files\java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe
```

Now comes the problems.

If I open two instances of Calculator, they have different `PID` values, so this value (the value itself, not the pointer!) is useless to me.

The title of the window depends on the state of the application (above, document opened in EditPad), so this is also useless. *(nb. some applications put the document in front of the title, so no pattern matching will ever solve this in the general case)*

The path is also useless as multiple copies of the same application can be ran from different locations on the disk, and the executable can be renamed too. I need all those cases to come up with the same application. Moreover, all java applications (like EditPad) point to the JVM.

Is there something I can do with PID, like get both the application and company names, as shown in Procecss Explorer, under the Description and Company Name columns? That would be perfect.

[image]

Comment: For the JVM, those will still be the same.  "Unique application" is a surprisingly vague concept.

Comment: As you see in the image, Process Explorer correctly displays EditPad's description and company, despite it being a javaw process. The combination of those strings is unique enough for me. (you can make it my 'definition' of unique, if you wish)

Comment: That's because it has its own EXE.  Those values are properties of the EXE file and will not vary.

Comment: Ok then. How can I get this EXE filename programmatically, and how do I extract those properties?

Comment: To get the filename, use the PID to open a handle to the process, then use [GetModuleFileNameEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683198%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [GetProcessImageFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683217%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: The second part of your question already [asked and answered here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2789017/886887).

Comment: Both GetModuleFileNameEx and GetProcessImageFileName return the Java executable instead of EditPadPro7.exe

Comment: Just here to let you know I've finally got the filename/commandline down, by getting it from the `RTL_USER_PROCESS_PARAMETERS` which I get from the `PEB` which I get from the `PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION` which I get with `NtQueryInformationProcess`. Phew. Tomorrow I'll try the second part.

Comment: Success! With `GetFileVersionInfo`/`VerQueryValue`. Although I can't give you rep if you don't post it as an answer.